# How do I disable GitHub Checks "Re-run" button?

Tags: github-actions

[image: rerun example]

I scoured everywhere in the docs. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#check-runs

At first, I thought it was the "actions" optional parameter in the UPDATE check API call. I thought it was some sort of default, so I added some dummy "Fix this" action. It added another button (NOT what I want).

So then I inspected the request that's made when I click the Re-run button, turns out, it is rerequest. https://github.com/w3-rre-test/ui-typescript-react/runs/4158592/rerequest

So then I looked everywhere for re-request, and i see it's a feature of Check Suite (but no way to turn that off).

It seems to call this endpoint: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#rerequest-a-check-suite

I don't want this feature, it's confusing my users. I also looked at this doc https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-repository-settings/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-a-repository#allowing-specific-actions-to-run, but I don't think it's the same "Action" api since i don't have the Actions tab in my org / repo.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a couple of years, but in the event someone stumbles across this and is curious how to do this:

At the time of writing, (Nov 2023) I'm not aware of a way to disable re-runs in GHA. However, there is a hack you put in on jobs you DON'T want users to be able to re-run.

Add this to the offending jobs:

```bash
if [ "$GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "This is a rerun."
else
  echo "No re-runs for you. Go away."
  exit 1
fi
```

Example:

```yaml
 no_reruns:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: No reruns please
        run: |
         if [ "$GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -gt 1 ]; then
            echo "No re-runs for you. Go away."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "not a re-run"
          fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try it
1.In the top right corner of GitHub Enterprise Server,

2.your profile photo, then click Your organizations.

3.Your organizations in the profile menu

4.Next to the organization, click Settings.

5.The settings button

6.In the left sidebar, click Actions.

7.Under Local and third-party Actions, select an option.

8.Enable, disable, or limit actions for this organization
Click Save.